# Converting syntax from mysql to postgresql

Tags: database

Currently I have to a function and a trigger which I wrote in mysql database as follow:

1. Create function:

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION cidr_overlap (cidr1 VARCHAR(30), cidr2 VARCHAR(30))
   RETURNS TINYINT
   BEGIN
   DECLARE bitmask INT;
   SET bitmask = pow(
       2,
       (32 - least(
           cast(substring_index(cidr1, "/", -1) as integer),
           cast(substring_index(cidr2, "/", -1) as integer)
       ))
   ) - 1;
   RETURN
       inet_aton(substring_index(cidr1, "/", 1)) & ~bitmask =
       inet_aton(substring_index(cidr2, "/", 1)) & ~bitmask;
   END
   ```
2. Create trigger:

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER no_overlap_cidr_a
   BEFORE INSERT ON a
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
   DECLARE msg VARCHAR(200);
   IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM a WHERE cidr_overlap(subnet, NEW.subnet))) THEN
   SET msg = CONCAT(
       'inserted subnet ', NEW.subnet,
       ' conflicts with existing subnets');
   SIGNAL sqlstate '45000'
       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
   END IF;
   END
   ```

This is link:  http://codepad.org/UXym69M6

Now, My backend DB is postgresql. Could you please help me with translation. I am trying convert but did not succeed.

Comment: Please format your code so it is easier to read. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help